# python unittest mocking class and inherit

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

Theres some class

```
# logging.py
class Logging:
    def debug(msg):  print(msg)
    def error(msg):  print(msg)


# index.py
from logging import Logging

def run():
    self.logger = Logging()
    logger.debug('hello world')
```

**case 1** : I wanna mock debug function to ignore print. how to mock up logging class?

test1 is mockup debug function. it works fine

test2 is mockup whole logging class. it doesnt work

```
# test1.py -> it works fine!
import index
from logging import Logging

def debug_mock(msg):  pass

@patch('logging.Logging.debug', debug_mock)
class Test1:
    def foo():
        index.run()


# test2.py -> not work
import index
from logging import Logging

class LoggingMock(Logging):
    def debug(msg):  pass

@patch('logging.Logging', LoggingMock)
class Test2:
    def foo():
        index.run()
```

**case 2** : I wanna mock logger in parent class just one time. how to?

If I cant, I have to mock up in every child class.

```
# parent_test.py
import index
from logging import Logging

def debug_mock(msg):  pass

@patch('logging.Logging.debug', debug_mock)
class ParentTest:


# test.py -> not work
class Test(ParentTest):
    def foo():
        index.run()
```

Comment: First, you are not mocking the class in the module where it is used, check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6). You need something like `@patch('index.Logging.debug')`. Second: are you writing an own logging module that has the same as the built-in logging? This would not be a good idea.